# Google Bigquery WHERE NOT IN function

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a query which would look like this in SQL. However in Google Bigquery, I can't seem to find the correct SYNTAX to execute this!

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country NOT IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');
```

Comment: Syntax looks good. What is the error message?

Comment: According to the documentation, that's exactly what you are supposed to be doing. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#in_operators

Comment: The issue should be in the "Country" column because the syntax looks good and works

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct. The issue is with the table name. In big query, you cant just write table name like this. You need to mention the dataset name as well. Even though you have not provided the error, I suspect the issue is because of missing dataset name and table name in backticks like

`dataset-name.table_name`

In your case, it should be

`Yourdataset_name.Customers`

The query should be

```
SELECT * FROM `dataset_name.Customers`
WHERE Country NOT IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');
```